# Jquery UI Accordion in hidden div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm struggling with this thing for hours now. I'm in desperate need of an expert eye.

So, im trying to set up an Jquery UI Accordion within pageslide. Pageslide is hidden wich unhides, then slides in. The accordion in pageslide is extremely buggy. The first header is always collapsed and the header i'm trying to target with a link doesn't open.

I asked my good friend Google for some advice. There are allot of people with the same problem. I'm absolutely sure it has to do something with the parent of the accordion being initially hidden.

Isn't there a way where I can fire up accordion after pageslide shows?

An example of this [can be found here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aWItNVwqStuRVELNTS2L?p=preview)
(click a link in the accordion to fire a second accordion within pageslide)

Minimized problem:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ac">
<h3>One</h3>
<div>
Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah
</div>
<h3>Two</h3>
<div>
Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah
</div>
<h3>Three</h3>
<div>
Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah
</div>
</div>
<script>
    $("#ac").accordion();
    $("#ac").hide();
    $("#ac").accordion('activate',2);
    $("#ac").show();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, instead of sending us the link to your website try to minimize your problem using jsfiddle or codepen. I would say just take minimalistic approach to build a buggy sample. Everyone including yourself will be able to understand and fix the issue faster.

Comment: sample doesn't show up the page slide and 2nd accordion.

Comment: Nothing about any of this makes any sense, can you maybe rewrite the question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9w9dU/1/) of how you should do it to work

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion glossWrap">
   <h3>titel</h3>
   <div>
      <p>Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec sed odio dui. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
   </div>
   <h3>titel</h3>
   <div>
      <p>Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec sed odio dui. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
   </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="glossary" data-panel="1">Open me</a>
```

JS:

```
var $accordion = $(".glossWrap"),
    panelId = parseInt(window.location.hash.replace(/#panel/, "")) || 0;

$accordion.accordion({
    collapsible: true, 
    active: panelId, 
    heightStyle:"content", 
    header:"h3"   
});

$("a.glossary").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var toOpen = $(this).data("panel");
    $accordion.accordion("option", "active", toOpen);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, really appreciate this! this isn't actually the problem though. The problem accours because of the initially hidden div. This causes the accordion to open up the first header as if he;s outside the accordion. (hard to explain, see code)

Comment: I don't understand why would you hide it first then activate the second panel and then show it up. Why don't you activate the second panel from the beginning?